# Why use ln-ln plot in proportional hazard test?

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions

I recently study survival analysis since couple of months ago, and there is one question which makes me curious. a simple and (maybe) a stupid question.

Why do we prefer to use ln-ln survival curve rather than survival curve in proportional hazard test? As you know, the $\hat{S}$ we use in ln-ln formula is survival function based on Kaplan-Meier, so why we don't use that 'original' KM survival function?

Comment: @NormalHuman : I think you're mistaken. What is intended here is not "analysis" in which mathematicians usually understand the term, but rather "analysis" as it is usually understood by statisticians.  (Except that for statisticians is is quite context-dependent and is understood in some contexts the same way mathematicians usually understand it.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I prefer to use statistics tag for this question. how?

Comment: If you have a function of the form y= a^x, then ln(y)= x ln(a).  The graph of that is a straight line so it is easy to read things like the intercepts and slope off the graph.  Using "log-log graph paper" makes that almost automatic.

Comment: I wonder if this would get better answers at stats.stackexchange.com? ${}\qquad{}$